# HTTP authorization headers not send with codeigniter api in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, http-headers, authorization

In API they call without Authorization is fine.

How to set header for it?
"thanks"

```
let headers: Headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' });`

let options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('latitude', '23.259933');
params.append('longitude', '77.412615');
params.append('nearby', '5');

return this.http.post(baseUrl, params, options)
            .map(
                (response: Response)=>{
                    return response;
                }
            )
```

Chrome console:

```
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: i have trying to post request with Authorization header but is not send and chrome console is return  "Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404"

Comment: Enable CORS on server where you are sending request.

Comment: ya i am also enable this cross using this [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) but authorization headers is not send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the browser sends the headers of your request to the server *before* sending the actual request (what is called `preflight`) so as to verify your request complies with the CORS policy that is defined *in the server's configuration*.

So what you need to do is double check that the server you are contacting is configured properly to accept the request as you make it.

Make sure that your backend server is accepting not only the POST request but also an OPTIONS request for the same endpoint url. The OPTIONS request should just return with the success 200 code.

On that server you probably have something like "when a user hits endpoint `/abc` with request type `POST`, then return some data". You also need something that says "when a user hits endpoint `/abc` with request type `OPTIONS` return `200 OK`"

If all else fails you could try using [this plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) in your browser, but keep in mind this will help only continuing development and is a band-aid solution that won't work in production of course.